# What are the algebraic steps to transform this expression? (Part of differential calculus)

Tags: polynomials, differential-calculus, trigonometric-polynomials

sorry if this seems to be too easy for you, but I have struggled a lot with this expression and I don't get it how they got there:

[image]

How can $\sqrt{2x^2}$ become $4x^2$ ?

Comment: Mathoverflow is for research level math questions. Try math.stackexchange.

Comment: ah I see, ok. I will post on the other platform from now on.

Comment: you can delete this answer if you want, since it's off-topic. I cannot delete it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to multiply the numerator and the denominator by $2 \sqrt{2x^2}$ to obtain the second equation from the first.

Comment: thanks! how could I not see this...